# How to update grub after installing Ubuntu 14.04 through MAAS with Global Kernel Parameters?

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, kernel, maas

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with kernel version 4.4.0-71-generic via MAAS with the Global Kernel Parameter setting as "quiet splash".

I proceeded to disconnect the system from PXE boot and enabled local boot via the hard disk.

Finally I appended some kernel options to the file `/etc/default/grub` to enable hugepages and ixgbe Virtual Functions among other things. I executed commands `update-grub` and `update-grub2` and rebooted the system.

No matter what I try, the newly added kernel options are being ignored by the system on reboot and the output of the command `cat /proc/cmdline` shows the following:

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-71-generic root=UUID=a379cb57-3ed1-42ae-b349-972363d1af85 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

How do I alter the grub successfully? I see that this issue occurs only when installing via MAAS. If I install Ubuntu using a .iso file on a flash drive I face no such issue.

Comment: maybe you had installed grub-legacy by mistake, i saw, today apt install grub installed it in debian 10, and i had similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the grub config is not updated is because the sudo update-grub command is outputting the changed file to stdout. You need to update the file in /boot with the -o flag.

```
sudo update-grub -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Answer (score -1):

I discovered that if you're in a KVM doing reboot in cmd line would not work. You need to ask the reboot from outside. In my case I had to use proxmox to call a reboot on the VM.